# PHP Gettext - No translation

Tags: php, windows, translation, gettext, poedit

I am trying to use the PHP gettext extension in order to translate some strings.  All functions appear to return the correct values but calling `gettext()`/`_()` returns the original string only.  The PO/MO files seem correct and I believe I have set the directories up correctly.  I am running WAMP Server with PHP 5.3.10 on Windows (also tried running 5.3.4 and 5.3.8 because I have the installations).

Firstly, see `/new2/www/index.php`:

```
$locale = 'esn'; # returns Spanish_Spain.1252 in var dump

putenv("LC_ALL={$locale}"); // Returns TRUE
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale); // Returns 'Spanish_Spain.1252'

$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, './locale'); // Returns C:\wamp\www\new2\www\locale
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8'); // Returns UTF-8
textdomain($domain); // Returns'messages'

print gettext("In the dashboard"); // Prints the original text, not the translation.
exit;
```

I have created the following file structure:

```
www/new2/www/locale/Spanish_Spain.1252/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
```

I have also tried replacing `Spanish_Spain.1252` with: `es_ES`, `esn`, `esp`, `Spanish`,  and `Spanish_Spain`.

The PO file used to generate the MO is like so (only the relevant entry given):

```
#: C:\wamp\www\new2/www/index.php:76
msgid "In the dashboard"
msgstr "TRANSLATED es_ES DASHBOARD"
```

This was generated using PoEdit.  I have restarted Apache after adding any new .MO file.  Also note that I was previously using Zend_Translate with Gettext and it was translating correctly.  I wish to rely on the native gettext extension, though, in part because I am attempting to create a lightweight framework of my own.

Any help would be appreciated.

*Edit*: Amended directory structure.  Note - will be able to try recent answers within 24hrs.

Comment: Shouldn't your locale and directory be `es_ES.UTF-8`?

Comment: @mario I've tried that locale and directory but `setlocale()` then returns false.

Answer (score 3):

I set this up on my XAMPP instance and figure it out.

- Flat out setlocale does not work on Windows, so what it returns is irrelevant.
- For Windows you set the locale using the standard language/country codes (in this case es_ES is Spanish as spoken in Spain)
- Under your locale directory create es_ES/LC_MESSAGES/.  This where your messages.mo file lives.

  ```
  $locale = 'es_ES'; 

  putenv("LC_ALL={$locale}"); // Returns TRUE

  $domain = 'messages';
  bindtextdomain($domain, './locale'); 
  bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8'); 
  textdomain($domain); // Returns'messages'

  print gettext("In the dashboard"); 
  exit;
  ```

I am not sure if this made a different, but I did two things when creating the po file.  In poEdit under File -> Preferences I changed the *Line ending format* to Windows.  And after I created the initial po with poEdit I opened the file in Notepad++ and switched the encoding type to UTF-8 as poEdit did not do this.

I hope this at least points you in the right direction.

**References**

[PHP Localization Tutorial on Windows](http://phpmaster.com/localizing-php-applications-1/)

[Country Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd796943.aspx)

[Language Codes](http://www.science.co.il/language/locale-codes.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Your code mentions this as the return value from `bindtextdomain`:

```
C:\wamp\www\new2\www\locale
```

With the `setlocale` of `Spanish_Spain.1252` and `textdomain` of `messages`, calls to `gettext` will look in this path:

```
C:\wamp\www\new2\www\locale\Spanish_Spain.1252\LC_MESSAGES\messages.mo
```

But you created the file structure of:

```
www/new2/locale/Spanish_Spain.1252/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
         ^^
         www/ missing here
```

**Edit**

Okay, so that didn't help. I've created a test script on Windows and using POEdit like you:

```
$locale = "Dutch_Netherlands.1252";
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale"); // 'true'
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale); // 'Dutch_Netherlands.1252'
bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale"); // 'D:\work\so\l10n\locale'
textdomain("messages"); // 'messages'

echo _("Hello world"); // 'Hallo wereld'
```

My folder structure is like this:

```
D:\work\so\l10n\
    \locale\Dutch_Netherlands.1252\LC_MESSAGES\messages.mo
    \locale\Dutch_Netherlands.1252\LC_MESSAGES\messages.po
    \test.php
```

Hope it helps, although it looks almost identical to yours. A few things I found online:

- It's important to set the character set in .po file
- Spaces inside the localization file might have a UTF8 alternative, so be wary of key lookups failing. Probably the best thing to test first is keys without spaces at all.

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry - I copied that incorrectly.  I have actually created `C:\wamp\www\new2\www\locale\Spanish...` etc.  I will amend my question now.  Thanks for spotting that, though!

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion: you may need the full locale for the .mo file. This is probably Spanish_Spain.UTF8 or esn_esn.UTF8 or esn_esp.UTF8 (not 1252, as you change the code base).

To track what directory it's looking for, you can install Process monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). It spews out bucket loads on info, but you should be able to find out which file/directory is being looked for.

(My other thought is to check file permissions - but if you already had something similar in Zend_Translate, then probably not the cause, but worth checking anyway).

Sorry if not good - but might give you a clue.

Comment: Thank you - I'll have a look at the Process monitor later and see if it helps me out.  Could be exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508305/gettext-works-sometime/10508713#10508713). It works for me on windows and on linux also. The last values in the array works for windows. List of languages names can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). My catalogs are in

```
./locales/en/LC_MESSAGES/domain.mo
         /cs/LC_MESSAGES/domain.mo
```

Comment: @FandaI've tried using the Windows locale names (including `esn` and `esp` - as in my question).  I've just tried several examples directly from the post you linked to, setting the locale to `array('de_DE.UTF-8', 'de_DE', 'de', 'german')`.  I created a `locale/[VALUE-FROM-ARRAY]/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo` file for each of these values and restarted Apache before trying again - no luck.  All functions returning correctly, though.  Any further suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to rename lang subdir to 2 letters code? (locales/de/LC... ?

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried using gettext on Windows, but each time I had problems with gettext on linux systems, the reason was that an appropriate language pack was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be also that when you change your *.po and *.mo files, you have to **restart the Apache Server**. This can be problem, so you can use workaround - always rename these files to some new name and they will be reloaded.

Comment: @jasirPlease read my original question; I have restarted Apache whenever my .MO files have changed.  Thanks.