# Gettext works sometimes

Tags: php, translation, gettext

I'm working on a project and I need to user translation for it. So I decided to use gettext in php but it's working sometimes.

So I have a folder named lng and in this on I have a php file who call my lang file to translate my page.

Here is the code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['lang']) != '')
{
    setcookie('lang',$_GET['lang'], time() + 365*24*3600, null, null, false, true);
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
    $language = $_GET['lang'];
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['lang']) != '' )
{
    $language = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE['lang']) != '')
{
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    $language = $_SESSION['lang'];
}else{
    $language = 'fr';
}

  putenv("LANG=$language");
  setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $language);

  $domain = 'trad';
  bindtextdomain($domain, 'locale/');
  textdomain($domain);
?>
```

So I can check my $_SESSION and $_COOKIE, no problem he give me 'en' or 'fr' but he doesn't translate my file and I don't know why.

For the folder in lng it's : locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/trad.po (or .mo).
I try with LC_ALL and LC_MESSAGES but that doesn't change the result.

Did I miss something or made a wrong stuff?

Thanks a lot!

J.

Comment: $domain is the filename without extension : I work with the code here : http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/06/13/php.html

Comment: yes, I have my file in my LC_MESSAGE folder and the name of those file are trad.po and trad.mo.

Comment: Right, silly me to completely miss it in all the code.

Comment: No problem, I just need to find why this one doesn't work...

Comment: Are you sure you're in the directory you think you're in?

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same problem. Restart Apache Service solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using windows? If so, you must use [windows locale names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). Here is part of my class working for me on linux and also on windows (it simply has more options of locale names):

```
...
private function setLocaleByLang($lang)
{
    $map = array(
        'cs' => array('cs_CZ.UTF-8', 'cs_CZ', 'cs', 'czech'),
        'en' => array('en_US.UTF-8', 'en_US', 'en', 'english'),
        'de' => array('de_DE.UTF-8', 'de_DE', 'de', 'german'),
        'pl' => array('pl_PL.UTF-8', 'pl_PL', 'pl', 'polish'),
        'sk' => array('sk_SK.UTF-8', 'sk_SK', 'sk', 'slovak')
    );

    $locale = key_exists($lang, $map) ? $map[$lang] : $lang;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    putenv('LC_ALL=' . $lang); // for windows and gettext
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same error. My case is a bit different, and I'm starting to think it has something to do with threading, despite it happens since I changed my code.

I have a language bar:

```
<?php
    include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/resources/config.php");
?>

<div id='language_bar'>
    <a style="margin-left:50px" href="./index.php?locale=es_ES">
        <img src='<?php echo $config['paths']['images']['lang']?>/es_ES.gif'/>
    </a>

    <a href="./index.php?locale=en_UK">
        <img src='<?php echo $config['paths']['images']['lang']?>/en_UK.gif'/>
    </a>

    <a href="./index.php?locale=de_DE">
         <img src='<?php echo $config['paths']['images']['lang']?>/de_DE.gif'/>
    </a>
</div>
```

And a config file with:

```
if (isset($_GET['locale'])) {
    $locale = $_GET['locale'];
    setcookie('locale', $locale, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
} else {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['locale'])) {
        error_log('En _COOKIE');
        $locale = $_COOKIE['locale'];
    }
    else {
        $locale = $config['localization']['default_locale'];
        setcookie('locale', $locale, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
    }
}

putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

error_log('setlocale->'.setlocale(LC_ALL, "0")." Env ->". getenv("LC_ALL"));
error_log(_("Submit"));
```

My main page has some divs interacting via jQuery, and reloading in cascade. Sometimes, some of them (randomly) give a default string value.

by default, it is in spanish (es_ES), and after a few clicks forcing div refreshes, some string is printed in english (en_UK original string). And what is more. If I switch to german (de_DE), after a first refresh where I get every string in german, gettext starts to reurn strings in spanish, and after a while, in english.

Note that I added debug lines to php log. They are really interesting:

When things go right:

```
[Thu May 31 00:28:51 2012] [error] [client ::1] setlocale->es_ES Env ->es_ES
[Thu May 31 00:28:51 2012] [error] [client ::1] Aplicar, referer: xxxxxxxx/index.php
```

When do not:

```
[Thu May 31 00:29:45 2012] [error] [client ::1] setlocale->es_ES Env ->es_ES, referer: xxxxxxxxx/index.php
[Thu May 31 00:29:45 2012] [error] [client ::1] Submit, referer: xxxxxxxx/index.php
```

So I guess it's _() function failing (I'm always using the alias). Just in case, I looped for 10.000 times over the function, and it gave or 10.000 hits or 10.000 mistakes while translating, so it fails for a whole http request, or doesn't.

My apologies for writing so much, but I would really appreciate some help pointing me in the right direction. (This error occurs not just @ my localhost, but also at my online test server)

¿might have anything to do with the fact that I'm setting the locale for every connection?

My online "playground" is:

Linux server8.nixiweb.com 2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 27 19:49:27 BST 2011 x86_64

My server:

Linux filete 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64
PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1

Note that both are 64bits

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Sometimes the strings were translated and sometimes don't. I have 3 servers for this application and 5 developers' machines, all with the same problem.

I solve it by removing:

```
bindtextdomain("domain", "/locale");
```

And linking the .mo file directly on the gettext default folder:

```
sudo ln -sf /myproject/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/domain.mo /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/domain.mo
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.