# PHP GetText Commands not working on command line

Tags: php, gettext

I'm trying to use gettext on a website, and for that I'm following the [O'Reilly Media tutorial](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/06/13/php.html?page=1). At the end of page one, it is saying that I need to use the command `xgettext -n *.php`, but my command line returns the following: `'xgettext' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
I'm running my website on XAMPP, so the my whole directory is like this:
`xampp/htdocs/gettext/locale/en/lc_messages/`

I have my test.php in the gettext folder, and the messages.po in the `en` folder. Even when I try to use poedit, it doesn't work. Here is my test.php code:

```
<?php
// I18N support information here
$language = 'en';
putenv("LANG=$language"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

// Set the text domain as 'messages'
$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, "localhost/gettext/locale"); 
textdomain($domain);
echo "<br>";
echo gettext("A string to be translated would go here");
?>
```

I'm not really sure the string in the bindtextdomain function is correct.
Anybody have any clue?

EDIT.:I forgot to mention that I was using Windows. I've already checked the php directory, the gettext extension is there, and it is enabled in the php.ini configuration file.

Comment: Make sure you've got it installed: `sudo apt-get install gettext` (if running a lamp setup)

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that I was using Windows. I've already checked the php directory, the gettext extension is there, and it is enabled in the php.ini configuration file.

Comment: Well, I should of noticed anyway because `XAMPP` :) Looks like you might need a different approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/10610166/292735

Answer (score 3):

I've found solution!
Try  add this line

```
putenv("LANGUAGE=$language");
```

According to [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Internationalisation/InternationalizationPrimer/Gettext):

> (Note that previously Ubuntu used the LANG variable for translation
>   language. Now LANGUAGE is used for this, and LANG is used to specify
>   other types of locale information, such as date formats, number
>   formats, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I had the same problem and your reply helped me a lot :)